# python regular expression get only data between two strings

Tags: python, regex

I am not sure how to get data between two strings the first or opening string "USER ID" and the last or closing string "You can".

I want everything including numbers periods, special characters etc.

But I also want to include the two strings in the data that is kept (these opening and closing strings represent data that I want).

How do I write the expression to get the data in between these string while also including my strings as part of the result?

**what it looks like**

```
Body:  Results of
User ID User Score  Full Score  Passing Score   Passing Status  Post Date   Elapsed
1   6   7   5   Pass    2014-9-3 16:12:27   00:00:25
Student Information
Student information
E-mail s
First Name  s
Last Name   s
Information on each question
Question    Question Type   Points  User's Response(s)  Correct Answer  Result
1. A
2. 
3. In l
4. The 
5. A 
Congratulations, you passed!
You can import
```

**what I want**

The line which includes Body: (including the word "Body:" and everything down to but not including the the second break word "you can" (where the case of my two strings could be either upper or lower case.

so I would end up with lots of:

```
Body: something
1. some question
you passed
```

or

```
Body: Something
1. You a...
2. Another
You Failed
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the input looks like and what you want the output to be?

Comment: `re.match(r'USER ID.+?You can', haystack)`

Comment: thanks paulo - when I test it over at pythex (regex editor) I can't get it to work.

Comment: You may have to turn on the "dotall" flag to make the dot match anything including the end-of-line characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it is not recursive, regex will do:

```
In [1]: import re                                                                                                                              

In [2]: haystack1 = "Foo, bar, USER ID bla bla bla You can - cheese"                                                                           

In [3]: haystack2 = "Foo, bar, USER FOO bla bla bla You can - cheese"                                                                          

In [4]: haystack3 = "Foo, bar, USER ID bla USER ID bla bla You can foo You can - cheese"                                                       

In [5]: for haystack in (haystack1, haystack2, haystack3):
   ...:     m = re.search(r'USER ID.+?You can', haystack)
   ...:     if m:
   ...:         print(haystack, "->", m.group(0))                                                                                              
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print(haystack, "->", "NO LUCK")
   ...:         
('Foo, bar, USER ID bla bla bla You can - cheese', '->', 'USER ID bla bla bla You can')
('Foo, bar, USER FOO bla bla bla You can - cheese', '->', 'NO LUCK')
('Foo, bar, USER ID bla USER ID bla bla You can foo You can - cheese', '->', 'USER ID bla USER ID bla bla You can')
```

If you look at `haystack 3`, you will see why it will not cut for recursive string snippets (like HTML/XML tags).

Now explaining the regular expression: `.+` will match anything, the dot means any character and the plus sign means one or more. The problem with `.+` is that it is "greedy", it will match anything including your terminator string "You can" until the end of the string. So we must add the `?`, in this context it means "don't be greedy". Not to be confused with the construction `x?` that means zero or one occurrences of 'x'.

[update]

Since you updated the question with a multiline example, you may have to include the re.DOTALL modifier:

```
haystack = "Foo, bar\nUSER ID bla\n\t\nbla\nbla You can\n cheese"                                                                           
m = re.findall(r'USER ID.+?You can', haystack, re.DOTALL)                                                                        
if m:
    print(haystack, "->", m)
else:
    print(haystack, "->", "NO LUCK")
```

The `re.DOTALL` modifier means that the dot will match anything including end-of-line characters.